# Change <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> to https?

Tags: html, xhtml

What happen if I change http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtm to https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtm?
Will my website works correctly?
Anyone could explain to me. thank you.

Comment: https is just a secure connection, as far as i know. if https is existing then nothing should change

Comment: Mr Listener, I changed it into https but when I use console log in browser, I saw it print http, so I think this option is read-only, cannot change

Comment: @Artemis That's odd; are you sure it was a real XHTML file, i.e. with .xhtml for an extension or application/xhtml+xml for a MIME type? If it was a HTML file, this behaviour would be expected, because HTML ignores the xmlns attribute.